Is chess for the elites?
I've been reflecting on the nature of chess and wanted to open up a discussion on something that crossed my mind: Is chess an elitist hobby?
Chess has often been associated with intellectualism and strategy, and it's sometimes portrayed as a game for the highly educated or those with a particular level of cognitive ability. This has led me to wonder whether chess might be seen as elitist or exclusive in some way.
On one hand, chess is a game that can be played by anyone, regardless of background. It’s accessible online and in communities around the world, with plenty of resources for beginners to improve. However, some might argue that the way chess is perceived or the emphasis on rankings, ratings, and mastery could make it feel less inclusive to those who are just playing casually or don’t have access to coaching and training resources.
What do you all think? Is chess truly an elitist hobby, or is that just a stereotype? How do we make the game more inclusive and welcoming for everyone? I’d love to hear your thoughts and experiences on this!

No, chess is not for elitists. In every area of life, there are nice people and those that are unkind to others, rude, mean, etc.  Chess is no different.  In online video games, there are people banned for rude comments to others.  There are many beginner-friendly chess YouTube channels (e.g., Eric Rosen).  Chess is a game.  Enjoy it.  Stay away from mean people and immerse yourself with other kind people who also enjoy the game.  It doesn't seem that complicated.

You appear to be trolling, trying to get people riled up. That is against the Code of Conduct. I would encourage you to read the help and about sections of the site to get a better understanding of how SE works.

The science fiction writer, Jerry Pournelle, used to tell a story about his fellow science fiction writer, Robert Heinlein. He claimed that Heinlein once said that:

Writers have a technical term for readers who believe that the opinions of the characters in a story are the opinions of the author. We call them "idiots"

Pournelle and Heinlein are both dead and so this exact quote is hard to track down but there is evidence of the same sentiment expressed in less insulting language by Heinlein from this form reply letter found and posted on Reddit:

A novelist writes from many viewpoints; opinions expressed even by a first-person character are not necessarily those of the author. Fiction is sold as entertainment, not as fact.

Something similar could be said about YouTube videos. When your videos get hundreds of thousands of views (or even tens of thousands) then YouTube pays you money. Whatever reason you had to produce them in the beginning they are now a form of entertainment which allow you to earn money.
Many, many people take advantage of this, including strong chess players. You are right that GMs, like Ben Finegold for instance, often use derogatory names for weaker players, names like "Doofus and Goofus". However, you are wrong to take this personally and wrong to think that they only insult weak players. If there is money (YouTube views) in it they will happily insult strong players too.
A few years ago Finegold and fellow GM, Simon Williams, concocted a money-making plan similar to two boxers scheduled to fight for a title. The build up including insulting each other, Finegold's on YouTube and Williams on Twitter. Here is an example of this.
This culminated in a grudge match which they both live-streamed and which was also live streamed by Chess.com (495K views Warning: strong language alert. Don't view if easily offended).
Two or three years later Finegold put out a YouTube video titled "Great Players of the Past: Simon Williams" in which he praises Williams and presents some of his best games.
Go figure, as they say. All the name calling was just to boost the ratings of the videos and make money.

Is chess for the elites?

No, it is for everybody who enjoys to play. Making lots of money from YouTube videos about chess is for the elites.
